# visual studio changing value of line in multiple files

Tags: visual-studio

[image]I have a 1000 json files, I need to change the value of a specific line with numeric sequence in all files.

An example

the specific line is

"name": "carl 00",

I need it to be like following

File 1

"name": "carl 1",

File 2

"name": "carl 2",

File 3

"name": "carl 3",

I can call the whole line in all the files by .*(name).* but I can't figure out how to change the name to the above example in visual studio.

Thanks.